# How to populate a dropdown box with a database query instead of a list in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

this could be a very easy question but as I novice I have to ask here sorry as I have not found the answer so far after a lot of playing with it.

I'm using flask with a python list of food types to allow users to input a food item into a form and have this verified with validators to make sure the item is in the list. The inputted food items from the form then gets stored in a db table.

I wish to replace this list approach with a sql query from a db of pre defined food types, whilst using the SQLAlchemy as this is used elsewhere in the app.

A simplified version of the code is as follows: -

```
#db connection is already setup and working OK in another part of the app
DB_URL = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@{url}:{port}/{db}'.format(user=POSTGRES_USER, pw=POSTGRES_PW, url=POSTGRES_URL, port=POSTGRES_PORT, db=POSTGRES_DB)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#example of the list
eaten = ['bread', 'crackers', 'ham', 'bacon']

#where the 'food_word' variable gets defined from an input and validated
food_word_1 = StringField('add the food type you have eaten here:', validators=[Optional(), AnyOf(eaten)])
```

I've tried replacing the list with `eaten =  db.execute('SELECT food_name FROM food_type')` (table  & column) with no luck.

I'm not sure if I need to create some kind of class/methods in the model.py for this Select/GET operation or even use something like pandas (which I also have in the app) to do this job.

Any guidance appreciated!

thanks, md

Comment: What is the result you get from that query?

Comment: In fact I get an error so no result unfortunately. I will reply to Naveneetha's suggestion with the error massage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is an Object Relational Mapper. It helps to interact with the database without SQL query. It is an abstraction to the database. So you should not write SQL query here. Rather you have to create an inherited class from db.Model. Like below.

```
class FoodType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    food_name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.food_name
```

Then for fetching data, you have to call the query function,

```
 db.query.all()
 # or
 db.query.filter_by()
```

The result will be a single list.

If you using postgres directly, without SQLAlchemy, then SQL query will be like,

```
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('SELECT food_name FROM food_type')
>>> cur.fetchall()
[['bread'], ['crackers'], ['ham'], ['bacon']]
```

If you want to convert as a single list,

```
eaten = [i[0] for i in db.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Nathaneethta and I played around with this but still getting an error which I captured here ** File "/hold/hold/forms.py", line 21, in <module>
    db.execute('SELECT food_name FROM food_type')
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute ‘execute' **. I'm starting to think it could be something more basic so as I imported this database table (for the other tables I use in the app I created them), do I need to create a 'model' class for this to be referenced?

Comment: yeah. if you are using sqlAlchemy then you have to create Class. i thought you were using normal postgres module. I mean without SqlAchemy. Let me edit the answer then,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance @Navaneetha as it helped me a lot realizing I had not created a model for this new database table as I am still in leaning mode here. Once the new model code was added in the models.py, in the forms.py I used the code `eaten = Food.query.order_by(Food.food_name)` and it works well!